# How can I use the function debian-run-directories in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: ubuntu

I had this code in my emacs config to load/include any additional config in the site-start.d folder. It worked well on two debian machines, but currently I need to use Ubuntu 18 with emacs 26.3 and it fails.

```
(setq dotfiles-dir (file-name-directory (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name))))          
(let ((user-site-start-dir (concat dotfiles-dir "/site-start.d")))                        
     (debian-run-directories user-site-start-dir))
```

From a related answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27676611 I understood it is both available in debian and Ubuntu. The error I get on start is:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/foo/.emacs.d/init.el’:

Symbol's function definition is void: debian-run-directories
```

What is the easiest way to use it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 does not have emacs 26 in its repositories, so it has been installed from source or from a ppa that doesn't include the debian patches.

The function `debian-run-directories` is defined in `debian-startup.el` that is part of the `emacsen-common` package, you can install it with

```
sudo apt install emacsen-common
```

After the package installation you may need to add `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/` to `load-path` before loading `debian-startup.el`.

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp")
(load "debian-startup")
```

Comment: Thank you! Just for the record, the problem was the same with the package emacs25 (25.3.2) but adding your lines to my init.el solved it.